# gdb During startup program exited with code 127

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, debian

Wanted to use gdb as a debugger in Linux Debian. Trying to run a binary I get this:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/local/sbin/test 
/bin/bash: /usr/local/sbin/test: No such file or directory
During startup program exited with code 127.
(gdb)
```

I guess it's supposed to be elementary. But  I googled a lot and most common answer is

```
$ export SHELL=/bin/bash
```

This doesn't help. I also tried to change PATH for binaries execution, tried to run from different directory... Still the same.

Could you please help me  with that?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [MCVE].

Comment: Do you really build your program "test" in "/usr/local/sbin"?  On my ubuntu system, that folder is owned by root, and takes root privileges to work in.  You need a very good reason to risk working with root privileges.   Please tell us how you compiled your program.  The error you are getting says the 'test' executable is not found.  So you need to find it, or build it.

Comment: What's the output of `file /usr/local/sbin/test` ?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN "/usr/local/sbin" was just one of the locations i tried

Comment: @Mark output was "Reading symbols from /usr/bin/test...(no debugging symbols found)...done."

Comment: Anyway an answer down there resolved the problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `/bin/bash: /usr/local/sbin/test: No such file or directory`

There are two common causes of this:

1. the file `/usr/local/sbin/test` doesn't exist
2. the file does exist, is a dynamically linked executable, and the ELF interpreter that it specifies does not exist.

For #1, the answer is obvious: you need a file to debug.

For #2, you can find out which ELF interpreter the file requires like so:

```
readelf -l /usr/local/sbin/test | grep interpreter
```

You likely have a 32-bit binary pointing to `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` on a 64-bit system without 32-bit runtime support installed. Depending on the distribution you are using, something like `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386` should do the trick.

---

Recent versions of the `file` command also print the interpreter:

```
file ./a.out 
./a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ... interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really the case.64-bit system without 32-bit runtime support. Works fine now.

Comment: @humme1 I have the same problem, but mine is  64bit binary so the output of above command is `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]`. Any idea?

Comment: @PMat Are you running this binary on a 64-bit Linux system? Approximately *nothing* should work on it if `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is missing.

Comment: @EmployedRussian. Yes i am on a 64-bit linux and /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 exists on my machine.

Comment: @EmployedRussian that was confusing, I installed the above package anyways, now gdb loads the binary but it says can't find the so files even though there are in the solib-search-path

Comment: @PMat You should probably ask a separate question, with details of what is installed on your system, what exactly you observe, whether the program runs outside of GDB, etc. etc.

Comment: @EmployedRussian sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46437172/gdb-failed-to-load-so-files-even-and-errors-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @EmployedRussian Hi, struggling with same problem, libc6:i386 is already installed, set SHELL env, `build-essential` is already the latest version. Tried everything, but nothing worked out. Please help

Comment: @PMat Hi, struggling with same problem, libc6:i386 is already installed, set SHELL env, `build-essential` is already the latest version. Tried everything, but nothing worked out. Please help

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
export SHELL = path

as in your case:

export SHELL=/usr/local/sbin/test

Answer (score 0):

It may help you. Allow all users to execute the file like this before gdb.

```
chmod +x file
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem on centos7, and solved it by installing gdb8.1.