# GDB failed to load so files and errors No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb, alpine-linux

I am loading a core file into GDB inside a docker container with alpine linux.
Initially my gdb complained about binary not found, then i followed this discussion [gdb During startup program exited with code 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021595/gdb-during-startup-program-exited-with-code-127) and installed libc6-compat, even though I have a 64-bit linux and my interpreter for the binary is 64-bit `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]`

That actually worked but now i get the same error for the .so files. I can see that .so files are in the path set on solib-search-path but gdb did not load any of the libraries and complains No such file or directory.

binary runs on a production host where the libraries are in the path
I am running the binary on a development host by setting the solib-search-path

ldd binary says libraries not found which is expected since this is a development host

Comment: You are missing a lot of details. Does the binary run outside of GDB? Where are the libraries? What is the output from `readelf -d a.out`? From `ldd a.out`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> binary runs on a production host where the libraries are in the path I am running the binary on a development host by setting the solib-search-path

There is your problem right here.

The `solib-search-path` is the path where *GDB* will look for libraries.

In *no way* does that setting affect the binary itself, which uses either standard system library path, compiled-in `DT_RPATH`, or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to search for shared libraries.

Usually, `solib-search-path` should only be set when you are analyzing a core dump that came from *some other host* (GDB needs access to the exact libraries that were used when the core dump was generated). Setting `solib-search-path` while running a local binary should never be ncessary -- GDB can automatically deduce where the libraries are by asking the runtime loader where they are.

> ldd binary says libraries not found which is expected since this is a development host

If `ldd` says that, then *of course* you will not be able to run the binary (inside of outside GDB).

Comment: I have set the solib-search-path and loading a core file even now gdb shows `No shared libraries loaded at this time`.

Comment: @PMat A) You seem to be asking a totally different question yet again, and B) you are not providing nearly enough details while doing so. I don't see how anyone can help you given the info you have provided.

Comment: Actually, re-reading your question, I *think* it's a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10629444/50617